# connect-flash middleware not displaying messages

Tags: node.js, middleware, connect-flash

I have been trying to use the connect-flash middleware for messages but it doesnt seem to be working. I get the following error: ReferenceError: /Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/views/addstudent.ejs:14 12|

## Add a new Student

13| >> 14|

Welcome: <%= user.local.name %>

15| 16|  17| user is not defined at eval (eval at  (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12), :11:23) at returnedFn (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:493:17) at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:31) at View.render (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8) at Function.app.render (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:502:10) at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:777:7) at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/express-flash/lib/express-flash.js:29:16) at Query. (/Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/app/routes.js:78:15) at /Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19 at /Users/zc/Documents/tutorials/node-auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16 at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9) at process._tickCallback (node.js:336:13)

Here is my route:

```
  app.post('/addstudent', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.selectoptions);
  var studentDetails = {};
  var newStudent = new Student(studentDetails);  
  newStudent.save(function(err, student){
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log(student); 
   res.render('student', {
    user: req.user
  }); 
  });

});
```

I am using ejs for the templating. I'm not sure why I'm getting user not defined, even after passing it along as an object when rendering student view.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the client sends flash message to server successfully or not. I think the `req.user` might be undefined.

The client side javascript or something might failed to load connect-flash request's body.